# Calculating normals for curves using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, webgl

Now, this might seem like a silly question, but *how* do I calculate normals for a **curve**?

For calculating the normals of a **surface**, I wrote the following function some time ago, not thinking about the matter in the meantime...

```
function calcNormals (source, destination) {

  var subtract = function (a, b) {

    var vec3 = new Array(3);

    vec3[0] = a[0] - b[0],
    vec3[1] = a[1] - b[1],
    vec3[2] = a[2] - b[2];

    return vec3;

  }


  var crossProduct = function (a, b) {

    var vec3 = new Array(3);

    vec3[0] = a[1] * b[2] - a[2] * b[1];
    vec3[1] = a[2] * b[0] - a[0] * b[2];
    vec3[2] = a[0] * b[1] - a[1] * b[0];

    return vec3;

  }


  var normalize = function (a) {

    var vec3 = new Array(3);

    var len = a[0] * a[0] + a[1] * a[1] + a[2] * a[2];

    if (len > 0) {

      len = 1 / Math.sqrt(len);

      vec3[0] = len * a[0];
      vec3[1] = len * a[1];
      vec3[2] = len * a[2];

    }

    return vec3;

  }


  for (var i = 0; i < source.length / 9; i++) {

    var index = i * 9;

    var v1 = [

     source[index],
     source[index + 1],
     source[index + 2]

    ];

    var v2 = [

      source[index + 3],
      source[index + 4],
      source[index + 5]

    ];

    var v3 = [

      source[index + 6],
      source[index + 7],
      source[index + 8]

    ];

    var p12 = subtract(v2, v1),
        p23 = subtract(v3, v2);

    var cp = crossProduct(p12, p23);

    var normal = normalize(cp);


    for (var n = 0; n < 3; n++) {

      destination.push( normal[0], normal[1], normal[2] );

    }

  }

}
```

So, this function works fine for arbitrary surfaces: I do only have to care about the vertices being in the right *direction*, then pass in the array where they are stored and add an empty array for the calculated normals.

But that of cause only works with **triangles**, but how would I calculate normals for **lines**?

Does calculating normals for a curve depend on how the curve itself initially was calculated, or could there be a function similarly general like the one written above, just using the array of vertices as input, so that I possibly could just extend this existing function?

Comment: Are you're looking for normals of a curve? That would be a plane. You'll get the same data from calculating the tangents and bi-tangents of vertices.

Comment: Isn't a "line" just a degenerate triangle?

Answer (score 4):

There are infinitely many possible normal vectors for a curve.

Generally:

- You find the curve's *tangent* vector by taking the derivative
  of the curve's function and normalizing it.
- Choose an arbitrary vector orthogonal to the tangent vector
  and normalize it. This is the *normal*. One such vector
  is the normalized second derivative of the curve function. Another
  such vector is found by taking the tangent and an arbitrarily chosen
  vector, taking their cross product, and normalizing the result.
- Take the tangent and normal vectors and take their
  cross product, and normalize the result. This is the *binormal*.

The combination of tangent-normal-binormal is also called a *Frenet frame*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Peter! Well, taking into account, that a line doesn't have just two possible directions, unlike the triangles, I kind of expected the need for additional parameters anyway, like defining some basic direction, but I hoped I could calculate the normals independently from the function which created the curve. However, I am not that skilled in math yet, so this is going to be some challenge...

Comment: You can approximate a derivative by using the difference quotient `(f(x+h)-f(x))/h` and choosing an appropriately small value for `h`.  I've added more information in my answer on finding a normal.